# How the td width render if total width of them is more or less than 100% table width

Tags: html, css

My table has 3 columns. I try to understand how the browser render column's width in each case:

1. Case 1: `td {width: 33.3%}` => Total width of 3 columns is equal 100%,
   so each column will be 1/3 of table width. It is easy and
   understandable.
2. Case 2: `td {width: 10%}` => Total width is 30% which less than 100%,
   but the browser still renders each column 1/3 of table width. My
   assumption is: If total width of  less than 100%, it will ignore
   this value (10%).
3. Case 2: `td {width: 50%}` => Total width is 150% which more than 100%.
   I dont understand the logic how the browser render each column width.
   Can anyone explain for me case 2 and 3?

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aej385mz/5/)

Comment: If you want to let the browser work properly, let it do that. (e.g. leave the width of a remaining column undefined, if the whole row has a fixed width, or leave the total width undefined, if that's what you want. Be happy that (if) the browser does something at all, if you supply conflicting requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easy way to solve this, you need to put a width / max-width to your table...

If you want all td's with 10%, just use table {width:30%;} and define all td's width: 10%;